# How to find an item in a QTreeView?

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, qfilesystemmodel

I understand that `QTreeWidget` has methods for finding an item, but since I want to use a `QFileSystemModel`, then I'm limited to `QTreeView`. However, I'd still like to be able to return all items from a `QTreeView` and place them into a list.

I had thought that I could go through and grab all indexes from the `QTreeView`, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Maybe something like:

```
QList<QModelIndex &> treeList;
foreach(QModelIndex &index, ui->tv_list)
{
     treeList.append(index);
}
```

but I know this isn't correct. What is a good way to get the items or addresses of items into a list from a `QTreeView`?

Comment: what model do you use?

Comment: @Zaiborg QFileSystemModel.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Are you trying to find one item, or are you trying to build a list of all items in the model?

Comment: All of them. I want to return all items from the model and place them into a list.